# Swift make custom class on UiPageController to hold text as Indicator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

so i was wondering is it possible to use page controller in swift but rather having dots as an indicator of each page, i can change it into string so its like a title rather than just a dots?

and i was wondering can i make the indicator it on top rather than at the bottom? cause usually the indicator of the page controller is on the bottom.

After some answer i found that creating a custom call is possible to change the dot indicator into a string,

can someone tell me how to do it?

im not very good at making custom class and i really want to learn how, i need a custome based on UiPageController to hold text/string as the indicator rather than dots.

[image]

Basicly i want to make that "Vouchers, Subsriptions, Mission" from UIPageController, and of course i can just put it into array so it would be completly dynamic

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can, the complicated and certain way you can do that is create your own class based on UIPageControl, and modify it to hold text.

The other easier but less certain way is to customize the image of the indicator with:

```
func setIndicatorImage(UIImage?, forPage: Int)
```

For more information check the link below on the section "Customizing the Indicator image"

[UIPageControl Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol)

Comment: ahhh i see.....okay well i think im gonna create a class, can you show me how to do it sir? or probably can you show me is theres any tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: I think this may help you. https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/building-a-custom-uipagecontrol-in-swift-3592af78a844#.4on1tddgz

Comment: The UIPageControl is basically UIButtons in a horizontal stack view